# Copy row of data based on criteria AND "label" that copied data in last column

Tags: excel, vba

I have working code that checks for a criteria in each row, and if met, copies that whole row of data over to a different workbook. But!  I need to be able to add text to the last column of the copied data (Column S) that essentially labels what criteria was met that made the code copy it over because I will soon be expanding to check for multiple different criteria.

So for every row that meets the criteria and gets copied, I want to add "Criteria1" next to it in column S in the new workbook (it will always be column S that will be the first available column).

I have mangled this code together through inheritance and all of your help, so I don't really even know where to begin.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)

Dim CoderBook As Workbook
Dim Referrals As Worksheet
Dim Review As Workbook
Dim Crit As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set CoderBook = Workbooks.Open("Coder Referrals.xlsx")
Set Referrals = CoderBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set Review = ThisWorkbook
Set Crit = Review.Sheets("Criteria")


'Search code
LastRow = Crit.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Loop search code
For i = 2 To LastRow

    'Specialized Criteria1 Check
    If Crit.Range("F" & i) <> Crit.Range("G" & i) Or _
    Crit.Range("I" & i) <> Crit.Range("J" & i) Then

            'If meets Criteria1 check, then copy appropriate rows to CoderBook Referrals sheet
            Referrals.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value = Crit.Rows(i).Value

    End If

Next i
'End loop code

CoderBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the or into two statements:

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
    j = Referrals.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1

    'Specialized Criteria1 Check
    If Crit.Range("F" & i) <> Crit.Range("G" & i) Then
        'If meets Criteria1 check, then copy appropriate rows to CoderBook Referrals sheet
        Referrals.Rows(j).EntireRow.Value = Crit.Rows(i).Value
        Referrals.Range("S" & j).Value = "Criteria1"
    End If
    If Crit.Range("I" & i) <> Crit.Range("J" & i) Then
        Referrals.Rows(j).EntireRow.Value = Crit.Rows(i).Value
        if Referrals.Range("S" & j).value = vbNullString then
            Referrals.Range("S" & j).Value = "Criteria2"
        Else
            Referrals.Range("S" & j).Value = Referrals.Range("S" & j).Value & ", " & "Criteria2"
    End if    
Next i
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense to me but it is putting the "Criteria1" label on the row associated with the data from the main book (Crit) rather than putting it in column S next to the data that gets copied over in the Referrals book (for instance, row 40 of data from the Crit book meets Criteria1, it gets copied to the Referral book, but then "Criteria1" is applied as label to row 40 instead of the row of the copied data in the Referral book)

Comment: Hm I am getting an error:  run-time error '1004' 
Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed

Comment: On what line? I can't test it since I don't know what your data look like. You may want to step through the code.  you'll have to do the debugging yourself

Comment: @Scott Craner edited my code (thanks BTW), try his version. Best way to debug code is to step through it (`F8`) and see the values of the different variables